# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200966), None) error

Tags: python, pywin32

**i was working on a jarvis ai in python im getting pywintypes.com_error**

**My error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\BiggestProject\MyAi\speak.py", line 4, in <module>
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 154, in getProperty
    return self.proxy.getProperty(name)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 185, in getProperty
    return self._driver.getProperty(name)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 70, in getProperty
    return [self._toVoice(attr) for attr in self._tts.GetVoices()]
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 70, in <listcomp>
    return [self._toVoice(attr) for attr in self._tts.GetVoices()]
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 60, in _toVoice
    return Voice(attr.Id, attr.GetDescription())
  File "C:\Users\Win7\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py", line 1750, in GetDescription
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(4, LCID, 1, (8, 0), ((3, 49),),Locale
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200966), None)
```

**My code**
import pyttsx3

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices',voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
  engine.say(audio)
  engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Are you literally running Windows 7, as your username implies?  Have you upgraded the Speech SDK?

Comment: Yes i am running windows 7 But i Dont Know how to upgrade it

Comment: Windows 7 released with SAPI 4.  Does it work if you use 'sapi4' as the engine?

Comment: it give a error       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi4'